# Make div in flexbox grow on hover

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-transitions

I'm trying to implement a view that displays three columns. When the user hovers over one of them it should grow at expense of the others.
I have a few requirements:

- I want each column to have a background image and it should not move when the column is resized.
- There should be a smooth transition when columns grows/shrinks
- It should work in at least Safari, Firefox and Chrome

I would also like to have each column separated by diagonal line if possible. This is what the end result should look like:

[image: end result]

I have basic functionality working, but I've run into several problems:

- I've not managed to get the background image to be fixed on the parent div
- Transitions does not work in Safari
- In the real context, which is a website based on Bootstrap, the background image moves by a pixel or two seemingly by random on Safari and Chrome.
- I've tried to achieve the diagonal lines using clip-path, but it does not work in Safari and very poorly in Chrome
- When changing column from the second to the third the first column is resized a bit
- In Chrome the rightmost pixel column flickers while growing/shrinking

Any hints appreciated!

Here's my current code:

```css
.content {
  display: flex;

  border: 1px solid #f00;
  background: #fbb;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 800px;
  color: #fff;
}

.col {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  transition: flex-grow .3s;
  -webkit-transition: flex-grow .3s;

  border: 1px solid #0f0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.col:hover {
  flex-grow: 5;
  transition: flex-grow .3s;
  -webkit-transition: flex-grow .3s;
}

.col1 {
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/130184/pexels-photo-130184.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.col2 {
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/354939/pexels-photo-354939.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.col3 {
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/259915/pexels-photo-259915.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="col col1">
    <h1>Foo!</h1>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col col2">
    <h1>Bar!</h1>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col col3">
    <h1>Brovinkel!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look into `transform: skew()` to tilt the items, where you also need to _widen_ them to cover the view and then revert that _skew_ for text/image (for the image a pseudo is a good holder). For issues mentioned that is not reproduced in the posted snippet, we can only guess (if someone take the change to answer that).

Comment: I've tried to skew and unskew with little success. Here's my best attempt: https://codepen.io/jomag/pen/qPGEWN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `transform: skew()` one can tilt the items.

As that will create an unfilled upper left and lower right area, widen the left/right will cover that.

Finally we then revert that skew for text/image, where I used a pseudo for the image.

Stack snippet

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 5px solid #f00;
  background: lime;
}

.col {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  transition: flex-grow .3s;

  transform: skew(-20deg, 0);
  background: yellow;
}

.col + .col {
  border-left: 10px solid #0ff;
}

.col:first-child {
  margin-left: -100px;
}
.col:last-child {
  margin-right: -100px;
}

.col::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% + 200px);
  margin-left: -100px;
  display: block;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  transform: skew(20deg, 0);
}

.col:hover {
  flex-grow: 3;
  transition: flex-grow .3s;
}

.col1::before {
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/130184/pexels-photo-130184.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb);
}

.col2::before {
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/354939/pexels-photo-354939.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb);
}

.col3::before {
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/259915/pexels-photo-259915.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb);
}

.col h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  transform: skew(20deg, 0);
}

.col:first-child h1 {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="col col1">
      <h1>Foo!</h1>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col col2">
      <h1>Bar!</h1>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col col3">
      <h1>Brovinkel!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer is very close to answering all my questions above. it does not fix the background, but i solved that by fixing the background in first column to left side, the third column to right side and second column to center. That worked perfectly for first and third, and good enough for the second column.

Comment: @Jonatan That sounds great :)